# Disable previous days in jquery datepicker using minDate

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am trying to disable previous days on a calendar using minDate: 0 but for some reason, its not working, here is my code;

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var arrDisabledDates = {};
    arrDisabledDates[new Date('02/22/2018')] = new Date('02/22/2018');
    arrDisabledDates[new Date('02/04/2018')] = new Date('02/04/2018');
    arrDisabledDates[new Date('02/16/2018')] = new Date('02/16/2018');
    arrDisabledDates[new Date('02/28/2018')] = new Date('02/28/2018');

    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function (dt) {
            var bDisable = arrDisabledDates[dt];
            if (bDisable) return [false, '', ''];
            else return [true, '', 'highlight'];


        }
    });
     $('#datepicker').datepicker({
         minDate: 0
     });

});
```

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    minDate: new Date()
});
```

this would work

Comment: Please explain what you did. Avoid only code answer

Answer (score 0):

Try `minDate: new Date()`

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Restrict date range</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: new Date() });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Get further details from [jquery datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max)

Answer (score 0):

I have got a solution to my problem, here is my solution

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var arrDisabledDates = {};
    arrDisabledDates[new Date('02/22/2018')] = new Date('02/22/2018');
    arrDisabledDates[new Date('02/04/2018')] = new Date('02/04/2018');
    arrDisabledDates[new Date('02/16/2018')] = new Date('02/16/2018');
    arrDisabledDates[new Date('02/28/2018')] = new Date('02/28/2018');

    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function (dt) {
            var bDisable = arrDisabledDates[dt];
            if (bDisable) return [false, '', ''];
            else return [true, '', 'highlight'];


        }, minDate: 0
    })

});
```

I had to add `}, minDate: 0` at the end of `function (dt)` Thanks guys!

Comment: You can replace `minDate: 0` with `minDate: new Date()` it will also work.